# Jquery changing .val() works only for a split second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Initial problem:
due to a connection to an external API creating new order (`orders#create`) takes a few seconds and there is nothing I can do about in on my side. So I need to tell the user somehow, that page is actually doing something.

This is my js-code for validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit-order').on('click', function(e){
        var success = true;
        $("div.text-danger").remove();

        // a lot of validations, which set success to false if they fail


        if (success === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.submit-order').find('input').val('Please hold on a little bit');

        }
    });
});
```

If I omit the `e.preventDefault()`, then the (new) text displays only for a split second and then reverts back to "Proceed to payment".
I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089026/jquery-toggleclass-only-works-for-a-split-second-then-it-reverts-back-to-how-it/30097998) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445408/jquery-show-only-works-for-a-split-second) SO answers, that I really need to include it. Then, the text stays "Please hold on a little bit". But, of course, now, no order is created.

How can I achieve a simple user informing while the backend is working? I stumbled upon [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault), but is it really necessary to involve a complicated ajax call only for some text change?

**Update #1:**
I don't really think, that my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516783/javascript-calculator-result-flashes) one since the known solution does not work on my case.

**My solution:**
Upon research, I stumbled upon 'data-disable-with' option, which was exactly what I needed. Now my submit button (Rails, Haml markup) looks like this:

```
.submit-order
  =f.submit "Proceed to payment", data: { "disable-with" => "Please hold on a little bit"}, class: "btn btn-success-mod-uzhindoma margin-bottom-60"
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: The form submission is refreshing the page.

Comment: Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Yes: Prevent the form submission. If you search, you'll find that topic very well covered indeed.

Comment: Yes, don't submit a form, make "a complicated ajax call" :-) Short of even more complicated (and hacky) techniques  (such as hidden iframes), that is the only way to send data to the server while keeping the current page visible.

Comment: @Thilo alright, thank you very much, seems like there is no way around. Could you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder however, I don't want to explicitly prevent default action. I want to create new order, but since it take a bit too long, I want to display something to the user.